# Regex: match between last occurrence of a character and first occurrence of another character

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
COUNTRY/CITY/street_number_floor_tel
```

I'd like to extract what is after the last occurrence of '/' and first occurrence of '_'. So the result is:

```
street
```

So far I've managed to come up with this regex:

```
[^/]+(?=_)
```

which results in the following:

```
street_number_floor
```

So I basically don't know how to stop after finding the first occurrence of '_'.

Many thanks for any hints in advance!

Comment: Try `(?<=/)[^/_]+(?=_[^/]*$)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oIItBc/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks!  Will you add it as an answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<=/)[^/_]+(?=_[^/]*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oIItBc/1)

**Details**

- `(?<=/)` - a positive lookbehind requiring a `/` immediately before the match
- `[^/_]+` - 1+ chars other than `/` and `_`
- `(?=_[^/]*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires `_`, then 0+ chars other than `/` till the end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Is it possible to adjust this regex to match all occurrences of the substring between the last / before a new _? Like, getting 2 matches if you copy paste the test string in the demo?

Comment: @mathkid91 Not sure what output you expect, try `[^/_]+(?=(?:_[^/_]*)+$)`

Comment: I mean OP's string correctly gives 1 match. But if you duplicate the string to be COUNTRY/CITY/street_number_floor_telCOUNTRY/CITY/street_number_floor_tel, I am looking for a regex that can find "street" 2 times. In the demo, it will only match the last occurrence of "street", and ignore the first one.